Can an ExpressJS query not utilize every single parameter passed to it?
I've created an "upsert" function (aka update and insert) in ExpressJS, the guts of which is shown here:
  if (!isEdit) {
    query = 'INSERT INTO comments (media_id, user_id, parent_id, comment) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING comment_id';
  }

  pool.query(query, [mediaId, userId, parentId, comment], (error, results) => {

Now I want to add update capabilities so I expanded the code to this:
  if (isEdit) {
    query = `UPDATE comments SET comment = $4 WHERE comment_id = '${commentId}'`;
  } else {
    query = 'INSERT INTO comments (media_id, user_id, parent_id, comment) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING comment_id';
  }

  pool.query(query, [mediaId, userId, parentId, comment], (error, results) => {

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error: could not determine data type of parameter $1.  I take this to mean that I must reference every single parameter provided, even though the UPDATE doesn't require all of them.
Obviously I can expand the code to be more verbose though I'll be repeating lots of similar code.  So I'm curious if there's a way to avoid this error I'm getting?

Which dbms are you using?

Postgres is the DB.  I'm accessing it via Typescript and ExpressJS.
